# Sorgenfrey's topology- compact subsets

Tags: general-topology, compactness

Consider the topological space $(R,\tau_{sor})$

Are the atoms $\{x\}$ where $x\in X $ compact in Sorgenfrey's topology?

And in the usual topology?

To say if $\{0\}\times [0,\infty)$ is compact in $(R^2,\tau_u \times \tau_{sor})$ is it possible to say that as $[0,\infty)$ is not compact in $\tau_{sor}$ the product topology won't be compact?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Singletons, that means sets of the form $\{x\}$ for $x\in X$ are compact in any topology, as each open cover $(U_i)_{i\in I}$ contains a set $U_j$ with $\{x\}\subseteq U_j$ and then $\{U_j\}$  is a finite subcover. By a similar method one chows that all finite subsets are compact.

To show that $A:=\{0\}\times[0,\infty)$ is not compact in $\tau_u×τ_{sor}$,  find an open cover without a finite subcover. Such a cover can be 
$\left[\frac12,1\right)∪\left\{\left[0,\ \frac12-\frac1n\right)\middle| n\in\Bbb N\right\}$. Then as the projection of $A$ onto $τ_{sor}$ isn't compact, $A$ cannot be compact either.

Comment: I can not explain that as $[0, \infty)$ is not compact in $\tau_u$ then $\{0\} \times [0, \infty)$ won't be compact in the product topology? Why is it not correct?

Comment: Sure, you can also use the fact that $[0,\infty)$ isn't compact in $\tau_u$, so it isn't compact in the finer topology $τ_{sor}$. The reason why I gave that specific cover in my answer was that I wanted to present a cover which explicitly uses open sets from $τ_{sor}$ as that is the space where $[0,∞)$ lives in.